# My method is executed in twice when in view didappear

Tags: swift, viewdidappear

My method is executed twice when in viewdidappear()

**Code**

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getaccountdetails()
    }

     func getaccountdetails(){
    if let sumacheck=UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "objectid"){
        print("results\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: 
         "objectid"))")

             do {
            let query = PFQuery(className:"Customer")
            query.whereKey("objectId", 
                  equalTo:UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: 
            "objectid") as! String)

            var name=try query.getFirstObject()["name"] as! String
            var email=try query.getFirstObject()["email"] as! String
            var phonenumber=try query.getFirstObject()["phonenumber"] 
           as! Int

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

}
```

**Output**:

```
results("wqe234234")
results("wqe234234")
```

My method is executing twice I don't know what makes it happens, but I also  noticed another problem that when I load any methods in view disappear it takes time to give results as like asynchronous task

Comment: Maybe unrelated but consider [*If you override this method, you must call `super` at some point in your implementation*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear)

Comment: What is that UIViewController inherited from?

Comment: Uiresponder @SwiftStudier

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at the call stack. Is `viewDidAppear` called twice? Maybe you're pushing/presenting this view controller twice?

Comment: Maybe your calling the viewcontroller more than one time